# Android Studio build.gradle warning message

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After i have successfully updated to Android Studio 3.1 Canary 9 i am getting warning message as

```
Warning:Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018
```

I know this warning will not cause any problem in my project at least for now. But i want to remove it totally so that there will be no problem in future at all. But after reviewing my build.gradle file i cannot find any line of code which has invoked this warning at all.

Here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.project.virtualdiary"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Probably a sub project or dependency is using Compile instead of implementation

Comment: So isn't that just cumbersome to display this?:)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/49574725/7457272][1] Upgrade the version of kotlin with new dependency follow above link. this may useful to you :)

Comment: Here is a complete and step by step solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/49892731/4648533](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49892731/4648533)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The problem lies in `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

The Google Services plugin is adding a dependency on behalf of you. Hopefully they fix it in the future.

Comment: problem solved. i updated google services following line in gradle project: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

Comment: I'm using com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0 and still the warning appears

Comment: We're 1 year in the future. Still experience this issue with google services at 3.2.1

Comment: Still experiencing this issue now.

Answer (score 44):

I have one same Warning caused to com.google.gms:google-services.

The solution is to **upgrade classpath com.google.gms:google-services to classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' in file in build.gradle Project:**

[image]

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In Android Studio verion 3.1 dependencies complie word is replaced to 
implementation

**dependencies with Warning** in android studio 3.1

```
dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
            compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    }
```

**dependencies OK** in android studio 3.1

```
    dependencies {
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    }
```

Gradel generate by Android Studio 3.1 for new project.

[image: Gradel generate by Android Studio 3.1 for new project.]

Visit  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_for_java_projects.html

For details https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html

Good luck

Comment: I've tried changing to com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0, but the warning still appears

Comment: **If you changed all the dependencies of complie to implementation.** The problem is that you can be external dependencies. Google has change complile to implementation in the com.google.gms version: google-services: 3.2.0 but other dependencies may not be up-to-date. you can try to update the other dependencies to see if in the new version we fix the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Niklas. I changed the `compile` to `implementation`, but the warning was gone only after the change in the *`build.gradle(Project: .....)`*

**before:**

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
```

**after:**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

first select :

1. ***Build***
2. ***Clean Project then Build***
3. ***make Project in Android studio***

Answer (score -2):

When AndroidManifest.xml package name was different from build.gradle package name i get this error

> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>   'implementation'. It will be removed at the end of 2018

[Java compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e89gx.png)

Comment: Depends on what you are targeting, but you are right, from the end of this month we must target 26> and in 26> `compile` is deprecated. But this is not the issue of this question.

Answer (score -4):

Change the "compile" to "implementation". this problem will be fixed! it works on my computer.

Comment: In the above examples all the "dependency" has already been changed to "implementation" I guess that's why this has been downvoted. I overlooked it in the above parts so this comment did help me.

Comment: read the question carefully!

Comment: Depends on what you are targeting, but from the end of this month we must target 26> and in 26> `compile` is deprecated. But this is not the issue of this question.