# Still getting warning : Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'

Tags: android, gradle, build, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have replaced every occurrence of `compile` by `implementation` in my project's `build.gradle`, but I'm still getting this warning :

[image]

I tried to look for "compile " in the whole project but no match was found. So what could be the cause?

Comment: Are you using a local library that is using 'compile' still?

Comment: @Devsil possibly... but how can I find out which one? I tried a Find in Path in the whole project but couldn't find any occurrence of `compile`..

Comment: If you are using a local library you will see its gradle.build file located in the project viewer on the right side of your Android Studio window. In that build.gradle file it may contain a "compile" as opposed to implementation. If any build.gradle file you see there doesn't contain that. It may be a library you are using that isn't local thus not giving you access to change that. So this warning can just be ignore for now.

Comment: Gradle should give the line number where the problem is occuring

Comment: try it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623244/error-configuration-compile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-with-implemen#answer-49595984 and for `Failed to resolve: android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1 Open File Show in Project Structure dialog` try to change version to `1.0.0`

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio build.gradle warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462550/android-studio-build-gradle-warning-message)

Answer (score 506, accepted):

I've updated `com.google.gms:google-services` from `3.1.1` to `3.2.0` and the warning stopped appearing.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0")

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    
    classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0")
    }
}
```

Comment: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018  


To be clear am not using any google service
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

  
    }

Comment: I get "Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0." when I try this. Update: changing it manually triggered lint warning when I changed it back to 3.1.1, then Alt+Enter to apply fix automagically changed it to com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0 with no errors on sync.

I'm not sure what the difference was but it's frustrating.

Comment: Alright, I believe I understand the difference. I had changed the Project and Module build.gradle gms classpath to version 3.2.0. It's the Module change that caused the problem. Change only the Project build.gradle gms classpath version.

Comment: I was also missing jcenter() repo! The project was very old and did not have that repo included!

Comment: Do you mean that I should just add that line manually to the file?

Comment: Done all as you said. Still getting same annoying warning

Comment: This answer is very close to truth, but I had such an issue without having com.google.gms plugin whatsowever. So it probably should be state that you need to update all plugins you have and hopefully they all already have new versions.

Comment: Worked for me, and with this I also had to change all play-services-*:8.4.0 to 9.0.0

Comment: I have the newer version of play services and `jcenter()` as well is added already. And this does not seem to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 126):

I have one same Warning caused to com.google.gms:google-services.

The solution is to **upgrade classpath com.google.gms:google-services to classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' in file in build.gradle Project:**

[image]

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In Android Studio verion 3.1 dependencies complie word is replaced to 
implementation

**dependencies with Warning** in android studio 3.1

```
dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
            compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    }
```

**dependencies OK** in android studio 3.1

```
    dependencies {
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    }
```

Gradel generate by Android Studio 3.1 for new project.

[image: Gradel generate by Android Studio 3.1 for new project.]

Visit  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_for_java_projects.html

For details https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html

Comment: Note that "testCompile" changes to "testImplementation".

Comment: most of the answers , and the most popular one as well , are all focusing on com.google.gms:google-services but it's all about updating the old naming style in both gradle files

Answer (score 32):

I've updated com.google.gms:google-services from 3.2.0 to 3.2.1 and the warning stopped appearing.

```
 buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

    }
}
```

Comment: you just need to change the version like I have this 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' you need to do just replace 3.2.0 with 3.2.1.

Comment: Thanks, I had updated the wrong class, that's why I got the error.

Comment: I have the version `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'` not most updated but yeah, it is greater than `3.2.0`. No resolution still!

Comment: @sud007 can you explain a bit what issue are you facing or post your build.gradle(Project level)

Answer (score 23):

Using the currently latest version of the google gms services resolved it for me.

In the project level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        ...  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Open up your build.gradle file located here:

[image]

This is the old way of writing the dependency libraries (for gradle version 2 and below):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
}
```

This is the new (right) way of importing the dependencies for gradle version 3:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/volley.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
}
```

Comment: Thanks friend! This seems like the most up-to-date answer here as of January 2019

Comment: This answer is helpful to those who are facing this issue for the first time. Although, OP has a different question, which says that even after those changes, error message is displayed.

Answer (score 12):

Reply by google : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74048134

There would be some dependency still using compile, check your application dependencies and transitive dependencies carefully.

Comment: I removed ALL dependencies in ALL build.gradles for my project and still get the error

Comment: EDIT: It was caused by realm, using older version

Answer (score 7):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72479188 indicates that plugins sometimes can introduce "compile" dependencies and that's what triggers the warning.  Probably just easiest to star that issue and wait until they fix it to point out which plugins are causing the issue.

Answer (score 6):

No need to remove the line. As Jkrevis wrote, update the com.google.gms:google-services to 3.2.0 and it stops the warnings.

Comment: Did you replaced every occurrence of 'compile' by 'implementation' in your project's build.gradle(Module:App) and updated the com.google.gms:google-services in build.gradle(Project) to 3.2.0 ?

Answer (score 6):

In my case,it is cause by Realm library,after I update it to latest version(5.1.0 so far) of Realm,the problem solved!

Here is the working gradle script:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.1.0"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
  }
}
```

Comment: The "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.0" was causing the issue for me. I updated to latest version and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 6):

I encounter this problem without using `com.google.gms:google-services`. 
The solution solving this kind problem as below:

1. check `build.gradle` files of all projects and modules. Or just global search key word 'compile' to find where cause this warning.
2. if above method cannot solve this warning, then use CLI Command, 

   `./gradlew assembleDebug -d > gradle.log`

   print detail debug information to a file named `gradle.log` or any else, as the information is too much. Then search word "WARNING" to find the position in `gradle.log`, usually you can find what dependence or plugin cause the warning.

Comment: I think this is the general solution. The problem could be caused by any one, or several, of your dependencies

Answer (score 3):

**Just updating google-service version did not work for me.**

- First make sure all your dependencies `compile` are replaced with `implementation`.
- Update all dependencies in your project. Because if one of your dependency is having `compile` then your project will show this error. So update all dependencies version.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried changing the **google gms services**  to the latest `com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1` in Android Studio 3.0.1 but the warning still persists.

As recommended by the compiler,I changed all `compile` dependencies to `implementation` and `testCompile` to `testImplementation` like this..

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

And finally the warning is removed!

Answer (score 2):

go to your build.gradle file in project level you will find the following lines highlighted

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'  //place your cursor over here 
    //and hit alt+enter and it will show you the appropriate version to select


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2' //the same as previously
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was an old dependency that was using compile for the transitive dependencies : `com.jakewharton.hugo`

After removing it from my gradle it compiled.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround to solve this problem was for me that I used an older version of Gradle, which can be found [here](http://services.gradle.org/distributions/):

I used the gradle-3.0-rc-1-src version, but others may work too, although probably it should not be newer than the 3.0-version.

First extract the zip file to anywhere you like.

Then go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle and change the setting to Use local gradle distribution. After that make sure that the Gradle Home-field is pointing to the .gradle directory in the directory you just unzipped to.

Rebuild the project and everything should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

The current version is **4.2.0**:

buildscript {

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Google updated it's services recently in September 2021. Gave update and I faced same issue then I update the build.gradle file in android studio

**Old version with issue**

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

**Updated code in build.gradle**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two options:

1. Add classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' in ur project: build.gradle dependencies
   and
2. Replace your module: build.gradle in dependency from complile with implementation
   and you wont get any warning messages.

Answer (score 0):

Just add from `build.gradle` from `build script`

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

and all of the dependencies `"compile"` replace to `"implementation"`.

that worked from me.

Comment: Note that if you're using `classpath` you must use it inside a `buildscript` block; moreover, one cannot use `implementation` inside a `buildscript` block.

Answer (score 0):

For me changing **compile** to **implementation** fixed it

Before

```
compile 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
compile 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
//Retrofit Dependencies
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

After

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
//Retrofit Dependencies
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I treid all the solutions mentioned here, but no luck.
I found in my build.gradle file as below:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    }
```

I just changed it as below and saved and tried build success.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Hope that you're affected with build.gradle(app)
If do so , follow this step

Replace **compile** with **androidTestImplementation** in build.gradle

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

so simple ! hope this will solve

Answer (score -3):

In my case the issue was the Google services gradle plugin with the following line in the gradle file:

> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Removing this resolved the issue

Answer (score -6):

go to you **build.gradle (app level)**

[build.gradle module app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vKSF.png)

and replace the word ***"compile"*** by ***"implementation"***

**it will work 100%**

Comment: This answer is not useful. The OP already stated that this was done, so it cannot possibly help.

Comment: i had the same issue, i couldn't generate my app apk bcoz of that, that answer solved my problem

Comment: This is not the same situation, OP already stated he's done this (I'm also in the same boat) it's due to dependancies

Comment: OP said "I have replaced every occurrence of compile by implementation".