# Adding Volley in dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to add Volley in build.gradle (Module: app):

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
}
```

and getting the following error:

```
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
```

What is the problem ? and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Still getting warning : Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709870/still-getting-warning-configuration-compile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

**instead of**

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```