# Gradle warning about "compile" even though none found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am making an Android app and I keep on getting the following warning. This warning is preventing me from connecting to Firebase on another PC when I clone the repo.

```
Warning:Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
```

I have replaced all "compile" with implementation but still getting the warning. Below is the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ak1195apps.employeelogs"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: What version of gradle you are using? Try updating to 3.2.0 : `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'`

Comment: seems a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709870/still-getting-warning-configuration-compile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replace

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to gradle 3.2.0 solved the problem.