# build.gradle compile deprecated warning

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to run an old project of mine on android studio, the project was last edited in 2017 and since then haven't been touched.

i keep getting an error to change the "compile" to "implementation" in the gradle file which i have done and still i keep getting the same warning

```
"WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced 
with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: 
http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app"
```

this is the actual code in the gradle file

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
```

it should build successfully without this warning, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Try build and rebuild.

Comment: i tried build/rebuild and clean and invalidate caches and restart, none worked for me

Comment: Tried updating all the outdated gradle stuff @MahmoudOmara?

Comment: Have you use another plugin in your `build.gradle`?

Comment: ^ yes i found the solution and it was related to another plugin in my project, i was using a very old version of realm database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was using a very old version of realm in my project

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.2.1"
```

after updating to

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.12.0"
```

the warning was gone and everything working again

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709870/still-getting-warning-configuration-compile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replace)

Just update

> com.google.gms:google-services

Answer (score 0):

Though i don't see any problem with your dependency list, use debug logs to identify which dependency is reason for this.
Compile using command line and collect logs in some file.

```
gradlew assembleDebug --debug > abc_1.txt

println("....1")
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
println("....2")
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
println("....3")
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
println("....4")
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
println("....5")
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
println("....6")
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
println("....7")
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
println("....8")
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
println("....9")
```

My example output

```
10:22:23.633 [QUIET] [system.out] ...1
10:22:23.633 [QUIET] [system.out] ...2
10:22:23.634 [QUIET] [system.out] ...3
10:22:23.634 [QUIET] [system.out] ...4
10:22:23.634 [QUIET] [system.out] ...5
10:22:23.634 [QUIET] [system.out] ...6
10:22:23.635 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' started
10:22:23.635 [WARN] [org.gradle.api.Project] WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
10:22:23.635 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute container callback action'
10:22:23.635 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute container callback action' completed
10:22:23.635 [QUIET] [system.out] ...7
10:22:23.635 [QUIET] [system.out] ...8
10:22:23.636 [QUIET] [system.out] ...9
10:22:23.636 [QUIET] [system.out] ...10
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:
Go to File > Sync project with Gradle Files

Then with the system finishes Sync

Go to File > Invalidate cache and Restart

Hope it works