# Warning: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In myapp/build.gradle i dont using compile configuration but stay desplay this warning

> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>   'implementation' and 'api'.

This us my app/build.gradle

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.apoce.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    defaultConfig{
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
    implementation 'com.jude:swipebackhelper:3.1.2'
    implementation 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Maybe a 3rd party library is still using `compile`, since it's a warning I think you can neglect it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Still getting warning : Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709870/still-getting-warning-configuration-compile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replace)

Comment: Sorry, but how?

Comment: i update google sevices and the problem fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just update google sevices to last version and the problem fixed