# How to change "compileSdkVersion" to be compatible with the new "implementation" API?

Tags: android-studio, compilation, implementation

I replaced all "compile" to "implementation" in the build.gradle (Module: app) but I can't know how to change "compile" to "implementation" in "compileSdkVersion" to solve this error message (or look the screenshot below):

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onvib.jpg)

I need your help.
Thank you!

Comment: This link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623244/error-configuration-compile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-with-implemen?rq=1) Answers your question.