# I am getting error: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'. It will be removed at the end of 2018

Tags: android-studio, gradle, plugins

I got this error after an update of Android Gradle plugin and Android Studio.

I have checked this question ([Android Studio build.gradle warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462550/android-studio-build-gradle-warning-message)), but I am not able to run the project.

Answer (score 23):

Step by Step solution

1- Go to the build.gradle(module app)

[image]

2- In the dependencies, you will see the code like this

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile  'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

3- Now you have to **ONLY replace** the compile with implementation and testCompile with testImplementation. Like this

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testImplementation  'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
implementation  'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
implementation  'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

4- That's all. Now click on Sync Now button.

[image]

**Note**- Don't change the number or version given specified in the code.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the complete solution:

**steps**

**1)** Use the new dependency configurations in gradle file
Replace compile with an implementation
For ex:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.3'
}
```

Should be:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.3'
}
```

b) Replace `testCompile` with `testImplementation`

For ex:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

should be

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

c) For library replace `compile` with `api`

**2)** Upgrade classpath com.google.gms:google-services to classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' in file in build.gradle (Use latest one)

**3)** File -> Invalidate Cache

Still Not Working: Then try below steps

**1)** Close the project.

**2)** Delete .gradle folder.

**3)** Open again the project

Now it will works

Answer (score 2):

Look at your dependencies in your build.gradle. anywhere you have compile, change to implementation.
For example:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.3'
}
```

Should be:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**just go to your app>> "Gradle Scripts" and open build.gradle(Project:"your project name") and change this line (classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0') to (classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'). current version 4.0.1**

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Explaination:**

since the **compile** is been obsolete in 2018 you must change this configuration as follows:
 1. open **build.gradle(module:app)** app file and make following changes in it.
 2. replace **compile** with **api** wherever api ref. like: volley, GitHub dependancy.strong text is used and
 3. replace **compile** with **implementation** incase of using android libraries like play-services-maps,appcompat-v7 etc.

example:
old way

```
  dependencies {
     testCompile'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

Change it to:

```
 dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

if the issue still persists:

open **build.gradle (Project: yourproject)** file
and change the google gms services to the latest

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Also if the gradle sync is still failing:

Open **gradle-wrapper.properties** file and replace it with following:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```