# How to use 'implementation/api' on Gradle 3.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

First of all, I need to make clear that I haven't much time in Android Studio and I just recently updated my Android Studio to the latest version. I realized I am using an outdated code and changed the '**compile**' Configurations in my root `build.gradle` file to '**implementation**' or '**api**' but it keeps giving me warnings.

I want to connect this project to Firebase but when I clicked the button it always told me to resolve Gradle errors or resync.

**[EDIT] Here's my code snippet:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.simplifiedcoding.firealert"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**[EDIT] This is the output on the Build Log**

```
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
```

Every time I did Gradle Sync it always give me error that mentions that '**compile**' Configuration is deprecated and that I need to replace them with '**implementation/api**'. The thing is, I didn't see a single '**compile**' Configuration line in my code.

Comment: Gradle 3.0 is rather old. Did you mean Android Studio 3?

Comment: Could you please add the full output, including the error message, to your question?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I edited the post. If u need any more details please direct me.

Comment: Hold on lemme try changing the classpath

Comment: Please check same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462550/android-studio-build-gradle-warning-message/49059867#49059867 

I thinks this line  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' may causes the issue

Comment: Blimey! Deleting the google-services plugin line did the trick! Thank you very very

Answer (score 0):

change the first line in-app level gradle file..

```
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Comment: That one still threw me the error so I changed it to api