# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'. > java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException (no error message)

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, compiler-errors

I am not sure why this is happening, but I did some digging and tried to find other solutions. None worked out especially duplicate questions:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }


}

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':react-native-customized-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-restart')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-fast-image')
    compile project(':lottie-react-native')
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.0.1"
    compile("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.54.0") { force = true }  // From node_modules

}
```

I deleted some duplicate `compiles` that I found and still no help. I noticed in the trace this warning:

`C:\ReactProjects\myapp\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:11:5-29:19 Warning:
    application@android:theme was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:11 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
C:\ReactProjects\myapp\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:16:9-19:35 Warning:
    meta-data#com.bumptech.glide.integration.okhttp.OkHttpGlideModule was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:16 to remove other declarations but no other declaration present`

I don't know if that will cause this whole thing to fail. Lastly here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapp"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  tools:replace="android:theme"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

Every problem that I had when trying to get a successful build I looked on SO or other sources, but this one takes the cake. I never inserted `compile "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1"` before and it worked before this problem occurred. Still no success.

The last thing I remembered doing is saving a file called 'safecode.js' in the home directory and basically it just has code that I want to save.

Comment: Visit the following link, hopefully you will get your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981156/tools-replace-not-replacing-in-android-manifest

Comment: or try to add this line in application tag at manifest file: tools:replace="icon, label" ---------e-g <application tools:replace="icon,label".

Comment: @Opriday I am still getting the error. I feel like since the manifest just has the warning it doesn't affect the build process, but I think it has something to do with `build.gradle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and I understand what a headache this can be. Here was my solution:

1) Make sure there are no duplicate dependencies in `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`

2) Most of you might not like this one, but I (hurts to type this) upgraded most things such as:

- compileSdkVersion 26 - `build.gradle`
- buildToolsVersion "26.0.1" - `build.gradle`
- distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip - `settings.gradle`
- classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0' - `build.gradle not in app directory`

**NOTE: Your Command Prompt's build UI will change and it does look overwhelming, but pretty cool. You'll get used to it. Also, you might need to change those `compile` in `build.gradle` soon.**

Here is the solution for that: [Android Studio build.gradle warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462550/android-studio-build-gradle-warning-message)

That should be pretty much it, but I'll also tell you other things I did that might affect your `BUILD FAILED`:

1) You might need Java 8. JDK 1.8. Add this to `build.gradle app directory`:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

2) Get rid of `compile "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1"`

3) `targetSdkVersion 22 update to 26`

And lastly,

4) In `build.gradle not in app directory`, put `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` in both repos.

**NOTE: You could use `google()` in place of that, but it didn't work for me so I stuck with `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }`.**

**ALSO TO NOTE: You might get messages saying, `"WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.0."`. Hey, 26 seems to be our magic number, if it works, then don't touch it. Unless you are absolutely certain you need to.**

To my knowledge and experience the warnings you get from the build process won't affect your `BUILD SUCCESS` or `BUILD FAILED`.

I hope this works for everyone!

Comment: Yes! Green build success! Thank you so much. Your second step worked for me. @AndrewI.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.