# "Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'."Warning keeps coming up again and again

Tags: android

So I am posting this after much research:

[Android Studio build.gradle warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462550/android-studio-build-gradle-warning-message)
[Still getting warning : Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709870/still-getting-warning-configuration-compile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replace)

**As many of the solutions suggested,I upgraded my google-services version to 3.2.0.**
Still the warning is coming up.

N.B. My project is using a lot of libraries:

Here is **project level build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.8.3'
        //classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Here are all the libraries in **app level build.gradle**

dependencies {

```
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:$MULTIDEX_VERSION"

    implementation("com.bottlerocketstudios:barcode:$BARCODE_VERSION@aar") {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation "com.bottlerocketstudios:javalockboxlib:$JAVALOCKBOXLIB_VERSION"
    implementation "com.bottlerocketstudios:vault:$VAULT_VERSION"

    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$GLIDE_VERSION"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:$GLIDE_OKHTTP_VERSION@aar"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$OKHTTP_LOGGER_VERSION"

    implementation "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:$FACEBOOK_SDK_VERSION"

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION"

    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$BUTTERKNIFE_VERSION"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:$RX_BINDING_VERSION"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-support-v4:$RX_BINDING_VERSION"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:$RX_BINDING_VERSION"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-design:$RX_BINDING_VERSION"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-recyclerview-v7:$RX_BINDING_VERSION"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:$THREETENABP_VERSION"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$TIMBER_VERSION"
    implementation "com.jakewharton:process-phoenix:$PROCESS_PHEONIX_VERSION"

    annotationProcessor "com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    implementation "com.squareup.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:$RETROFIT_VERSION"

    implementation "com.f2prateek.rx.preferences:rx-preferences:$RX_PREFERENCES_VERSION"
    implementation "com.trello:rxlifecycle:$RX_LIFECYCLE_VERSION"
    implementation "com.trello:rxlifecycle-components:$RX_LIFECYCLE_VERSION"
    implementation "io.reactivex:rxjava:$RX_JAVA_VERSION"
    implementation "io.reactivex:rxandroid:$RX_ANDROID_VERSION"

    implementation "pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location:$REACTIVE_LOCATION_VERSION@aar"
    implementation("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$CRASHLYTICS_VERSION@aar") {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation "com.contentful.java:java-sdk:$CONTENTFUL_JAVA_SDK_VERSION"
    implementation "uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:$CALLIGRAPHY_VERSION"
    implementation "com.flurry.android:analytics:$FLURRY_ANALYTICS_VERSION"


    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.1'

    testImplementation "junit:junit:$JUNIT_VERSION"
}
```

Here are some important library version I am using :

```
OKHTTP_VERSION=3.8.1
RX_PREFERENCES_VERSION=1.0.0
PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=15.0.1
BARCODE_VERSION=1.0.3
CONTENTFUL_JAVA_SDK_VERSION=7.5.0
BRFONTVIEW_VERSION=1.0.0
JUNIT_VERSION=4.12
BUTTERKNIFE_VERSION=7.0.1
DAGGER_VERSION=1.2.2
RX_ANDROID_VERSION=1.0.1
RX_JAVA_VERSION=1.0.14
JAVALOCKBOXLIB_VERSION=1.0.0
RX_BINDING_VERSION=0.3.0
CALLIGRAPHY_VERSION=2.1.0
SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION=28.0.0-beta01
RX_LIFECYCLE_VERSION=0.2.0
REACTIVE_LOCATION_VERSION=0.8
RETROFIT_VERSION=2.3.0
CRASHLYTICS_VERSION=2.6.2
FACEBOOK_SDK_VERSION=4.23.0
```

The warning I am getting:

```
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html


Configuration 'debugCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'debugImplementation' and 'debugApi'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
```

Any idea which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Have u tried `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

Comment: Still the warning is coming up

Comment: @kgandroid try invalidate cache and restart the android studio

Comment: Do you have a module specific Gradle file? If so, have you checked that file for "compile" references?

Comment: Invalidate cache and restart not working :(

Comment: I do not have any module specific gradle files

Comment: Would you please try to use `SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION=27.1.1` instead of `28.0.0-beta01`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with jakewharton hugo plugin which I was using in the app

```
classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
```

Relevant link:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo/issues/156

Answer (score 3):

Just replace:

`compile`  with `implementation`

`testCompile` with `testImplementation`

`debugCompile` with `debugImplementation`

`androidTestCompile` with `androidTestImplementation`

`compileOnly` is still valid. It was added in 3.0 to replace provided and not compile.

Changes with Gradle 3.0 is officially [announced at GoogleIO17](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ll-rkLCtyk&feature=youtu.be&t=22m20s).

The `compile` configuration is now deprecated and should be replaced by `implementation` or `api`

Check out Gradle Documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation)

Warning you are getting is due to the libraries you have imported are you using `compile` keyword in the gardle.

Comment: @kgandroid, Please check your imported libraries

Comment: @kgandroid, You can just ignore this warning or can wait for your library creators to update there gradle system.

Answer (score 0):

With the hot key  "CTRL + Shift + F"  try to search for "compile" keyword.If there is no modification left, please go to file -> Invalidate Caches/Restart.These error messages will be gone.

Comment: Done that a multiple times.After all those basic things are not working,I posted here

Comment: Then if these warnings are not creating any issue to run your app, you can ignore them.Sometimes these warning comes in android studio again and again

Comment: I need to resolve those to set up firebase and also to make my app clean and latest.

Comment: Is it stopping your app to run?

Comment: This will not enable you to setup firebase directly from the android studio itself.Also as a developer you dont want to have warnings in your code.

Comment: Really I will not want any warning in my code.Actually after the last gradle update these warnings come though we modify in specific locations.After sometime these warnings does not come.But it should not be a issue to set up the firebase.As you have posted I can see your code is clean and you do not need to modify the app.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

just replace compile-->implementation in app module, except compileSdkVersion in app module

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to upgrade `'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'` to `'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`